# Solve in set of natural numbers

Tags: number-theory, divisibility, diophantine-equations, congruences

Solve in set of natural numbers the following systems: 
\begin{align}
&\text{(a)} && x + y = 150,\quad \gcd(x, y) = 30\\[12px]
&\text{(b)} && \gcd(x, y) = 45,\quad 7x = 11y\\[12px]
&\text{(c)} && xy = 8400,\quad \gcd(x, y) = 20
\end{align}

I've tried Diophantine equations but it did not work.

Maybe there is a clever solution but so far I have been unable to spot it. Can anyone help me or give me any hint?

Comment: I think that diophantine eqns are enough to solve the problem. Why don't you show us your work?

Comment: For (a) i've got that ax+by=c, that a=1 and b=1, (a,b)=1, $x_1=0$, $y_0=1$, $x_0=0$, $y_0=150$, $x=0+k$,$y=150+k$ and i think that this isn't correct @Luis

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(a):
Since $gcd(x,y) = 30$, then $x = 30x_1$  and  $y=30y_1$, where $gcd(x_1, y_1) = 1$. Now substitute in the first equation and get $30(x_1+y_1) = 150$, then $x_1+y_1=5$. It has solutions $(x_1, 5 - x_1)$ where $1 \leq x_1 \leq 4$(all of these pairs are coprime) and $x = 30*x_1$.

(b):
$gcd(x, y) = 45$, then $x = 45x_1$ and $y = 45y_1$($x_1$ and $y_1$ - coprime). Then you have $7x=11y$, then $45*7*x_1=11*45*y_1$ which implies that $7$ divides $y_1$ and $11$ divides $x_1$. Notice that every divisor of $x_1$ is also a divisor of $y_1$ except $11$ and every divisor of $y_1$ is divisor of $x_1$ except $7$. But $gcd(x_1,  y_1) = 1$, So you must have $x_1 = 11$ and $y_1 = 7$ $\rightarrow$ $x = 45*11$ and $y = 45*7$ for all $x_2, y_2 \in \mathbb{N}$ and $gcd(x_2, y_2) = 1$

Generally when you have problems with $gcd(x, y) = d$ it is a good idea to set $x = d*x_1$ and $y = d * y_1$. I'll leave the third one unsolved(I can solve it if you can, but you can use it as an exercise).

Comment: $\gcd(x,y)=20$ then $x=20*x_1$ and $y=20*y_1$. Then we have $x*y=20$ then $20*x_1*20*y_1=8400$ then $x_1*y_1=21$, where $\gcd(x_1,y_1)=20$. Is this correct? And also I'm kinda stuck here @thefunkyjunky

Comment: Almost correct. Since $gcd(x, y) = 20$ then $gcd(x_1, y_1) = 1$. So you are looking for coprime numbers $x_1$ and $x_2$ with the property $x_1*y_1=21$. These pairs are obviously $(1, 21)$, $(3, 7)$ and their symmetric ones. About $gcd(x_1, y_1)$: suppose that $gcd(x_1, y_1) = d \geq 2$. Then $x_1 = d*x_2$ and $y_1 = d*y_2$, which means $x = d * 20 * x_2$ and $y = d * 20 * y_2$, hence $gcd(x, y) = 20*d$, which is impossible if $d \geq 2$